# How to minimize the window of IE Browser using selenium webDriver?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Need to minimize the window of IE Browser using selenium webDriver using c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that using selenium, but you can do it in C# using the Windows API:

```
private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
private const int SW_NORMAL = 1;
private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
private const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
private const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
private const int SW_SHOW = 5;
private const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
private const int SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7;
private const int SW_SHOWNA = 8;
private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
private const int SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10;
private const int SW_FORCEMINIMIZE = 11;
private const int SW_MAX = 11;

[DllImport("User32")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);

ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
```

Of course, you need to add User32.dll to your project.

Comment: Hm. You will need to get the window handle for the browser from Selenium somehow. Perhaps someone else can help you with that.

Comment: Can I use shortcut to minimize the browser

Answer (score 0):

Well it is possible only to maximize and resize the browser but not minimize it.

Have you tried sending the keyboard shortcut for it? It might work.

Though I am not sure why will you need to minimize a window (as Selenium is extensively for browser testing and nothing else).

Comment: Selenium can be used for scraping.